# Populate facet labels from another dataframe in facet_wrap ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to rename the facet labels in my plot and I have to read it from another dataframe. I already made a function to retrieve the right label for each business, but all the labels are printed in the facets, what is the problem?

```
df <- structure(list(Year_Month = c(
  "2016_06", "2016_06", "2016_07", 
  "2016_07", "2016_08", "2016_08", "2016_09", "2016_09", "2016_09", 
  "2016_09", "2016_10", "2016_10", "2016_10", "2016_10", "2016_11", 
  "2016_11", "2016_12", "2016_12", "2017_01", "2017_01", "2017_01", 
  "2017_02", "2017_02", "2017_02", "2017_02", "2017_03", "2017_03", 
  "2017_03", "2017_03", "2017_03", "2017_03", "2017_04", "2017_04", 
  "2017_04", "2017_04", "2017_04", "2017_05", "2017_05", "2017_05", 
  "2017_05", "2017_05", "2017_05", "2017_06", "2017_06", "2017_06", 
  "2017_06", "2017_06", "2017_06", "2017_07", "2017_07"), 
  Business = c("A", 
               "E", "A", "B", "B", "E", "F", "A", "H", "B", "A", "D", "B", "E", 
               "B", "E", "F", "B", "F", "B", "E", "A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "A", 
               "G", "D", "B", "E", "F", "A", "G", "B", "E", "F", "A", "D", "B", 
               "C", "E", "F", "A", "D", "B", "C", "E", "F", "A"),
  `MMR Count` = c(2L, 
                  1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 
                  4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 
                  2L, 15L, 7L, 4L, 27L, 2L, 14L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 31L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 
                  4L, 5L, 21L),
  `Duration Average` = c(37, 20, 9, 8, 2, 5, 1, 1, 
                         1, 14, 1, 19, 8, 1, 21, 77, 1, 18, 8, 1, 1, 194, 9, 14, 19, 1, 
                         10, 1, 6, 9, 18, 4, 12, 170, 7, 35, 9, 10, 7, 12, 3, 15, 5, 9, 
                         10, 10, 18, 11, 16, 14)), .Names = c("Year_Month", "Business", 
                                                              "MMR Count", "Duration Average"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")

df$date = as.Date(paste0(df$Year_Month, "_01"), format = "%Y_%m_%d")


#calculating the mean of data
library(tidyverse)
dMean <- df %>%
  group_by(Business) %>%
  summarise(MN = round(mean(`Duration Average`),2)) %>%
  mutate(label=paste(Business, " (Overall: ",MN,")"))


#function to retrieve the label of a specific business to be shown on the facet
get_mean <-function(string) {
  d_label <- dMean %>% filter(Business==string) %>% select(label);
  d_label= as.character(d_label)
  return (d_label)
}

appender <- function(string, suffix = get_mean(string)) paste0(string, suffix)


#plot
ggplot(df,
       aes(x=date,
           y=`Duration Average`,
           group=Business,
           color=Business,
           size=`MMR Count`)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Business),stat="identity", size=1, alpha=0.7) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Business, alpha=0.7)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Business, ncol=2, labeller = as_labeller(appender)) +
  scale_y_log10( limits=c(.1,1000),breaks=c(1,10,100,1000)) +   
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.5,1), guide='none') + 
  geom_text(aes(label=`Duration Average`,vjust=-1),size=3) +
  geom_text(aes(label=`MMR Count`,vjust=2),size=3,color="brown")
```

Comment: So what is the desired output? When asking for help, you should include a **minimal**reproducible example with desired output. Remove anything not directly related to your problem. Less code to scroll through make its easier to answer your question.

Comment: what I have shared is the reproducible example and not the original problem. if you look at the dMEAN dataframe, I want the column `label` to be the label for the facets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to just join `dMean` onto `df` and then facet by the label

```
df %>% 
  left_join(dMean) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=date,
             y=`Duration Average`,
            group=1,
             color=Business,
             size=`MMR Count`
           )) +
  geom_line(size = 1, alpha=0.7) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.7) +
  facet_wrap(~ label, ncol=2) +
  scale_y_log10( limits=c(.1,1000),breaks=c(1,10,100,1000)) +   
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.5,1), guide='none') + 
  geom_text(aes(label=`Duration Average`,vjust=-1),size=3) +
  geom_text(aes(label=`MMR Count`,vjust=2),size=3,color="brown")
```

[image]

Comment: I have done this and it has worked, but I don't want to distort the Business column in df

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the you mean by "distort the Business column"? Because joining `dMean` onto `df` does not affect the Business column. See `df2 <- df %>% left_join(dMean)` and then `identical(df$Business, df2$Business)`

Comment: yeah, I just noticed that the code is not manipulating the Business column and it is using the label column from the joined dataframe, but I am having a problem running it successfully, I tried it on rdrr.io and it is giving me this error: `Error in combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, vars, drop = params$drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`

Comment: Make sure your face argument looks like this `facet_wrap(.~ label, ncol=2)`

Comment: I managed to join the data frames and use the resultant df, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Try removing the period `facet_wrap(~ label, ncol=2)`.